# /index.php/ is inserted in the URL if redirecting from http://www. to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cloudflare, php-5.6

I have noticed some strange stuff regarding one of our websites. In ahrefs.com, the "Broken Backlinks" shows some strange things.

- PHP/5.6.40
- Server Version: Apache/2.4.39 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2s mod_bwlimited/1.4
- PHP-FPM not enabled
- Cloudflare has no implication in this. Tested it with and without it.

**.htaccess content:**

```
#--------------------------------------------------
# 301 redirect rules to https://www.
#--------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#------------------------------------------------
# Rules for normal site functionality, search, SEO friendly URLs, etc.
#------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^livenews/([^/]*)$ index.php?livenews=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

[image: WHM]

I have checked the redirects, they all work as intended. In the sitemap there is no error whatsoever. The issue only occurs, as it seems, when an old backlink is crawled by ahref.com's crawler. Same thing in Majestic.

**Note:** Yes, I need to use PHP5.6 because parts of the code are deprecated in newer versions.

A normal hyperlink's code to a non https version of a page looks good:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/maincategoryname/subcategory/page,1.html" class="anchor" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Dofollow backlink">more helpful hints</a>
```

Now, according to the report, this is 301 redirected to it's https version (as it should). HOWEVER, **/index.php/** is inserted into the URL:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/subcategory/page,1.html
```

which is, obviously, a 404 page.

Please notice the substitution of **/maincategory/** with **/index.php/**

The corect 301 redirect result should be, of course:

```
httpS://www.example.com/maincategoryname/subcategory/page,1.html
```

So, the 301 redirect rules does work for redirecting http://www -> https://www. But why the /index.php/ is replacing the /maincategory/?

The 301 redirect rules from the top of the .htaccess file should redirect anything that is:

- http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com (this is the most
  important to keep, actually... the website always had the www, so
  there are only a couple of backlinks pointing to the non www.
  version)
- http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
- https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

All URLs have proper canonical headers.

In the header I have these meta tags, if these could have any importance in that regard:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="TRUE" />
<base href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

It's a bit of an issue because it affects the user experience, link juice is lost and, overall, **annoys me like nothing else**. :) I know I am missing something, but I have no clue what.

On the live website I wasn't able to find any faulty redirect, but again, I have the SSL certificate installed for *example.com.

So, I am guessing that it has something to do with redirecting http://www. to the https version... and probably it's missing from somewhere a backslash. /

or, more probably

there is a conflict between the DirectoryIndex directive in Apache (prioritise index.html) and cPanel-generated handler for PHP?

**Reference:** check out the image, versus this code from the .htaccess file:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**Note**: that the homepage is indeed an index.html file. But I have an index.php one as well which serves anything else besides the homepage.

And this is the puzzle: what could be the reason that /index.php/ path is included in the URL replacing /maincategory/.

Thank you for any suggestion!

Regards,
Robert G.

Comment: I would suggest you enable rewrite logging, that can usually help figure out where stuff goes wrong with rewriting. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging (Careful with the trace log level, because this can log quite a lot of data. Start with 2 or 3, and only go higher if that doesn’t give _enough_ info to see what is going on.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try that out as well.